# Scala: Type Error When Enriching Collections

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-collections

So I'm trying to work through Norvig & Russell's "Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach" as a way to learn Scala. I have a pretty good grasp on the language basics at this point, but I still find myself often "fighting" the type system.

Long story short, breadth-first and depth-first search algorithms are the same aside from the mechanics of pushing/popping to their underlying collection. Depth-first would *prepend* new possibilities and use a Stack, while Breadth-first would *append* and use a Queue.

To keep my algorithm the same, I created a typeclass called "GiveGrab" (I know, horrible name) with the intention of pimping ... err ... *enriching* collections with these "default" push (give) and pop-like (grab) operations.For example, grab would result in a call to .dequeue() for queues, and .pop() for stacks.

Here's (a somewhat abbreviated version of) the code:

```
object Example extends App {

  trait GiveGrab[A, M[A]] {
    def give(x: A*): M[A]
    def grab(): A
  }

  implicit class GiveGrabQueue[T](q: Queue[T]) extends GiveGrab[T,Queue[T]] {
    override def give(x: T*) = q ++= x
    override def grab() = q.dequeue()
  }

  class TestClass[T, X <% GiveGrab[T, Queue[T]]](var storage: X) {}

  val test = new TestClass[Int, Queue[Int]](new Queue[Int]())

}
```

When trying to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
Error:(18, 39) scala.collection.mutable.Queue[T] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  class TestClass[T, X <% GiveGrab[T, Queue[T]]](var storage: X) {}
                                  ^
Error:(13, 67) scala.collection.mutable.Queue[T] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  implicit class GiveGrabQueue[T](q: Queue[T]) extends GiveGrab[T,Queue[T]] {
                                                              ^
```

That said, it took me a lot of trial and error to even get to this point. I'm not sure if my trait is really supposed to be typed
`trait GiveGrab[A, M[A]]`
or
`trait GiveGrab[A, M[_]]`
or
`trait GiveGrab[A, M]`

The error "takes no type parameters, expected: one" doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me at this point, and there's only a handful of other posts about that message (some related to dependent types, and some related to the Play framework).

Somewhat related: is there a good article for understanding Scala type signatures? I read through Programming in Scala 2nd Ed, but it didn't really touch on this sort of type gymnastics (either that, or I just missed it.)

Edit: Typos

Comment: If you change the definition to `extends GiveGrab[T, Queue]` and `class TestClass[T, X <% GiveGrab[T, Queue]]`, it's going to work just fine. I'm not *entirely* sure why such notation works (probably because `M[_]` conforms with already parametrized type `Queue[T]`), hence it's just a comment instead of an answer, but someone with more knowledge regarding higher-kinded types in Scala might shed some light here.

Comment: Just tested that and - as you said - it seems to work fine. At least I have a workaround while we're waiting for somebody to explain why. :) Thanks Patryk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @PatrykĆwiek proposed is not a workaround but actually what you are meant to be doing: `M[A]` in trait `GiveGrab` defines a type function. Roughly speaking this means: `M` is a type where you can apply a single type parameter to yield a concrete type. That the parameter is called `A` is pure coincidence. The following means the same:

```
trait GiveGrab[A,M[MyRandomName]] { ... }
```

In the definition of `give`, you actually use this type function to create a type, when saying `M[A]`. Therefore, as @PatrykĆwiek said, you should write `Queue` instead of `Queue[T]`. While `Queue` is precisely one of these type functions, `Queue[T]` is a concrete type and therefore doesn't apply to the definition of `M`.

The error message you get says exactly that: In the place of `M`, you are supposed to put a type that takes a parameter (like `Queue`), but you have put one which takes none (`Queue[T]` in your case, another example would be `String` or `Int`).

Comment: Thanks, that explanation makes sense. I think it didn't help that I wasn't "parsing" the error message properly, either.